# Why does cmd.exe stay open when I run a batch file opening many applications. How do I fix it (keep it closed)?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, cmd.exe

**This is my batch**:

```
@echo off
start "Start OneDrive" "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe"
start  "Start Google Sync" "C:\Program Files\Google\Drive\GoogleDriveSync.exe"
start "Start Clipboard" "C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4\BCClipboard.exe"
start "Start Cisco AnyConnect" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpnui.exe"
start outlook
start chrome
start firefox
start skype
start "Start Teams" "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\Teams.exe"
start Slack
start Zoom
sleep 15
taskkill /IM "explorer.exe"
taskkill /IM "teams.exe"
taskkill /IM "skype.exe"
taskkill /IM "slack.exe"
taskkill /IM "zoom.exe"
@echo on
```

I get **this error** when it hits teams (not the issue I am asking):
And It leaves CMD open with a flashing cursor due to an unhandled error in teams.
You can disregard the below error it is only for context.
**The point is the application errors causing CMD to stay open.**

```
(electron) The default value of app.allowRendererProcessReuse is deprecated, it is currently "false".  It will change to be "true" in Electron 9.  For more information please check https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397
Error while parsing hooks JSON. Error: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Teams\\hooks.json'"
(node:27472) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 ecsSettingsUpdated listeners added to [EventEmitter]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(electron) The default value of app.allowRendererProcessReuse is deprecated, it is currently "false".  It will change to be "true" in Electron 9.  For more information please check https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397
(node:27472) ProtocolDeprecateCallback: The callback argument of protocol module APIs is no longer needed.
(node:27472) ProtocolDeprecateCallback: The callback argument of protocol module APIs is no longer needed.
(node:27472) ProtocolDeprecateCallback: The callback argument of protocol module APIs is no longer needed.
(node:27472) ProtocolDeprecateCallback: The callback argument of protocol module APIs is no longer needed.
(node:27472) ProtocolDeprecateCallback: The callback argument of protocol module APIs is no longer needed.
(node:27472) ProtocolDeprecateCallback: The callback argument of protocol module APIs is no longer needed.
(node:27472) ProtocolDeprecateCallback: The callback argument of protocol module APIs is no longer needed.
(node:27472) ProtocolDeprecateCallback: The callback argument of protocol module APIs is no longer needed.
(node:27472) ProtocolDeprecateCallback: The callback argument of protocol module APIs is no longer needed.
(node:27472) ProtocolDeprecateCallback: The callback argument of protocol module APIs is no longer needed.
(node:27472) ProtocolDeprecateCallback: The callback argument of protocol module APIs is no longer needed.
(node:27472) ProtocolDeprecateCallback: The callback argument of protocol module APIs is no longer needed.
(node:27472) ProtocolDeprecateCallback: The callback argument of protocol module APIs is no longer needed.
(node:27472) ProtocolDeprecateCallback: The callback argument of protocol module APIs is no longer needed.
(node:27472) ProtocolDeprecateCallback: The callback argument of protocol module APIs is no longer needed.
(node:27472) ProtocolDeprecateCallback: The callback argument of protocol module APIs is no longer needed.
(node:27472) ProtocolDeprecateCallback: The callback argument of protocol module APIs is no longer needed.
(node:27472) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 appInitialized listeners added to [EventEmitter]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:27472) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: undefined
(node:27472) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:27472) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
Error occurred in handler for 'keychain:get-password': Error: No stored credentials fetched from keytar.
    at C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.SkypeApp_15.68.96.0_x86__kzf8qxf38zg5c\Skype\resources\app.asar\main.js:2:600216
    at async electron/js2c/browser_init.js:6048:30
Error occurred in handler for 'keychain:get-password': Error: No stored credentials fetched from keytar.
    at C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.SkypeApp_15.68.96.0_x86__kzf8qxf38zg5c\Skype\resources\app.asar\main.js:2:600216
    at async electron/js2c/browser_init.js:6048:30
(electron) 'systemPreferences.isInvertedColorScheme()' is deprecated and will be removed. Please use 'nativeTheme.shouldUseInvertedColorScheme' instead.
(node:27472) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: [RegistryKey] Unable to open registry key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\IM Providers failed: The operation completed successfully.
    at RegistryService.registerImProviderCu (C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\resources\app.asar\lib\registryService.js:586:72)
    at C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\resources\app.asar\lib\registryService.js:167:41
(node:27472) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
(node:27472) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: [RegistryKey] Unable to open registry key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\IM Providers failed: The operation completed successfully.
    at RegistryService.registerImProviderCu (C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\resources\app.asar\lib\registryService.js:586:72)
    at C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\resources\app.asar\lib\registryService.js:167:41
(node:27472) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)
SUCCESS: Sent termination signal to the process "explorer.exe" with PID 14384.
SUCCESS: Sent termination signal to the process "explorer.exe" with PID 25908.
SUCCESS: Sent termination signal to the process "Teams.exe" with PID 27472.
SUCCESS: Sent termination signal to the process "Teams.exe" with PID 25612.
ERROR: The process "Teams.exe" with PID 18836 could not be terminated.
Reason: This process can only be terminated forcefully (with /F option).
ERROR: The process "Teams.exe" with PID 27476 could not be terminated.
Reason: This process can only be terminated forcefully (with /F option).
ERROR: The process "Teams.exe" with PID 13548 could not be terminated.
Reason: This process can only be terminated forcefully (with /F option).
ERROR: The process "Teams.exe" with PID 20888 could not be terminated.
Reason: This process can only be terminated forcefully (with /F option).
ERROR: The process "Teams.exe" with PID 24916 could not be terminated.
Reason: This process can only be terminated forcefully (with /F option).
SUCCESS: Sent termination signal to the process "Teams.exe" with PID 23860.
ERROR: The process "Teams.exe" with PID 5708 could not be terminated.
Reason: This process can only be terminated forcefully (with /F option).
SUCCESS: Sent termination signal to the process "Skype.exe" with PID 22604.
SUCCESS: Sent termination signal to the process "Skype.exe" with PID 27620.
SUCCESS: Sent termination signal to the process "Skype.exe" with PID 5252.
ERROR: The process "Skype.exe" with PID 9844 could not be terminated.
Reason: This process can only be terminated forcefully (with /F option).
SUCCESS: Sent termination signal to the process "Skype.exe" with PID 7404.
ERROR: The process "Skype.exe" with PID 8976 could not be terminated.
Reason: This process can only be terminated forcefully (with /F option).
SUCCESS: Sent termination signal to the process "slack.exe" with PID 17188.
SUCCESS: Sent termination signal to the process "slack.exe" with PID 6704.
SUCCESS: Sent termination signal to the process "slack.exe" with PID 2868.
ERROR: The process "slack.exe" with PID 24196 could not be terminated.
Reason: This process can only be terminated forcefully (with /F option).
ERROR: The process "slack.exe" with PID 23300 could not be terminated.
Reason: This process can only be terminated forcefully (with /F option).
SUCCESS: Sent termination signal to the process "Zoom.exe" with PID 11976.
SUCCESS: Sent termination signal to the process "Zoom.exe" with PID 17976.
_
```

**All I want is for the applicaion to run and CMD not to stay open.**

**The application runs OK (error disregarded), but cmd.exe window stays open.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

THIS ANSWER DOES WORK. But For some reason it requires start of cmd with switch /c for each app. so multiple cmd.exe windows are opened and then closed. This requires a sleep 10, otherwise the taskkills would run too fast

I was finding that when I ran the teams app from a batch it would process happily but the rest of the batch would stop.
If I got the error the rest would process but cmd would stay open.

---

**Primary Batch change:**

```
@echo off
start cmd /c start "Start OneDrive" "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe"
start cmd /c start  "Start Google Sync" "C:\Program Files\Google\Drive\GoogleDriveSync.exe"
start cmd /c start "Start Clipboard" "C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4\BCClipboard.exe"
start cmd /c start "Start Cisco AnyConnect" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpnui.exe"
start cmd /c start outlook
start cmd /c start chrome
start cmd /c start firefox
start cmd /c start Slack
start cmd /c start Zoom
start cmd /c start skype
start cmd /c start "Start Teams" "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\Teams.exe"
sleep 10
taskkill /IM "explorer.exe"
taskkill /IM "slack.exe"
taskkill /IM "zoom.exe"
taskkill /IM "skype.exe"
taskkill /IM "teams.exe"
@echo on
```

---

I did **not** end up **putting the teams.exe into its own batch** to run in a separate context, it was flawed somehow.

I did not use this **Secondary Batch "StartTeams.bat"**

```
start "Start Teams" "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\Teams.exe"
exit /b
```

I definitely tried other suggested answer, unforunately it did not work for me.
My answer has changed numerous times, thinking I solved it only to introduce new issues.

---

But I think I have landed on the answer.
Keen to get some other answers as this subject is quite complex.
And I do not know why I had to use "start cmd /c start..." to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me I wasn't using the `start cmd /c`,  just `start` and getting errors. BTW I read that Windows now recommends Powershell to do this not the `CMD`